# Nuke Python list of objects order based on other list

Tags: python, list, sorting, object, nuke

I got two lists. First one looks like this:

```
passOrder = [
                    'direct_diffuse',
                    'direct_specular',
                    'direct_specular_2',
                    'indirect_diffuse',
                    'indirect_specular',
                    'indirect_specular_2',
                    'refraction',
                    'reflection',
                    'emission',
                    'sss'
                ]
```

and the other one is a list of objects - in this case Nuke nodes:

```
nodes = nuke.selectedNodes()
```

I'm trying to compare each node's name parameter with passOrder list and arrange them in the order given in passOrder. I tried to explicitly set up orderedNodes index but I guess it's not possible when the list is empty at start.

```
orderedNodes = []
for n in nodes:
    for index, p in enumerate(passOrder):
        if n['name'].value() == p:
            orderedNodes.insert(index, n)
```

I've also tried to zip both lists, and sort them - no luck here. Basically I have no idea how to iterate over `n['name'].value()` component when sorting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your class/function definitions look like, so I'm using these stubs to illustrate my solution:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.val = value
    def value(self):
        return self.val

class Nuke:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.n = {"name": Thing(name)}
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node({})".format(repr(self.n["name".value()))

def selectedNodes():
    return [Nuke("refraction"), Nuke("direct_diffuse"), Nuke("emission")]
```

You could sort `nodes`, using `passOrder.index` for its key parameter:

```
passOrder = [
                    'direct_diffuse',
                    'direct_specular',
                    'direct_specular_2',
                    'indirect_diffuse',
                    'indirect_specular',
                    'indirect_specular_2',
                    'refraction',
                    'reflection',
                    'emission',
                    'sss'
                ]

nodes = selectedNodes()
nodes.sort(key=lambda item: passOrder.index(item.n["name"].value()))
print nodes
```

Result:

```
[Node('direct_diffuse'), Node('refraction'), Node('emission')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to code the sort yourself.

```
ordered_nodes = sorted(nodes, key=lambda n: passOrder.index(n["name"].value()) if n["name"].value() in passOrder else len(passOrder))
```

Comment: This is preferable over my solution if it's possible that `nodes` will contain a Nuke whose name isn't in `passOrder`. Nice defensive coding.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks! In fact I saw your solution after I posted mine.

Comment: @S. de Melo Thanks for such an elegant solution. I'm trying to inject regex into this function to match layers name that start with strings given in passOrder, e.g. `direct_diffuse_layerName_2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a dictionary mapping node names to nodes like this

```
nodes_by_name = {n['name'].value(): n for n in nodes}
```

With this dictionary, it's trivial to retrieve the nodes in the desired order:

```
ordered_nodes = [nodes_by_name[name] for name in passOrder]
```

If there might be names in `passOrder` without corresponding nodes, you can simply skip them:

```
ordered_nodes = [nodes_by_name[name] for name in passOrder if name in nodes_by_name]
```

This approach is simpler and more efficient than trying to use sorting.